# Doctrine is trying to allocate 4GB?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, doctrine-orm

I mapped a Post object with Doctrine to the `wp_posts` table used by Wordpress. A column called `post_content` in this table is a `LONGTEXT` that can contains 4GB.

When I try to load the objects from these table, I receive the following message:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate **4294967296** bytes) in
>   /home/rdinhani/renato/php-lib/DoctrineORM-2.2.2/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php on line 165

This occurs when executing a query to load the objects (at the moment, only ONE row will be returned).

So, Doctrine is trying to allocate 4GB to load the value inside this column, but this overflow the memory. **I don't have large values inside this column, only a few texts.**

There is some configuration in Doctrine or PHP that can avoid it to try to allocate the 4GB to the column, or maybe, set the maximum limit in MySQL column to a smaller value like 2MB, 10MB, etc?

Comment: PHP usually reports the location of the error. I doubt anybody will be able to help you knowing only that at some unidentified location (possibly in Doctrine) you're running out of memory.

Comment: @lanzz You're right, I updated the message, but the only message I have is in Doctrine when I try to execute a query in the database.

Comment: Doctrine wont be padding out columns to meet the max size in your DB tables. What hydrator are you using for your query? also, can you show us the "Post" entity.

Answer (score 3):

Mysqli driver [has a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46808).

When try to select mediumtext or longtext field it tries to allocate the whole field size 2^32 bytes = 4294967296.

**Solution**: Change to PDO_Mysql or change the medium/longtext field to text field.